# Putting Gradient of a quadratic expression equal to zero and getting vector subtraction from a scalar

Tags: derivatives, normed-spaces, transpose

I have encountered this problem in my research and I want to take its derivative using closed form equation. But I get some scalar subtracting a vector in the end which I don't understand. Kindly help me with this. The problem is here:
$$\alpha_px^2+\beta_px+v_p^Tx+\rho/2||D_px||^2$$
Here alpha, beta are scalars, v is a vector and D is a matrix. The last squared term is 2-norm. I need to find extremal values i.e. put gradient equal to zero and then solve the equation for x which is a vector too.
I get $ x = \frac{-\beta_p-v_p^T}{2\alpha_p+\rho D_p^TD_p}$. Here $\beta_p$ is a constant(scalar) whereas $v_p^T$ is a row vector. How can they be subtracted? Am I doing something wrong? Would appreciate any help! Thanks

Here is the original problem if that is helpful:
[image]
Here $f_p(x_p) = \alpha_px_p^2+\beta_px_p$ which is a quadratic function and $v_p = \gamma_p^k - \rho \!\sum_{j \in \mathcal{N}_p}W_j x_j^k$.

As each node p belonging to $C_1$ can solve the problem separately and then add so there is no need of this summation $\sum_{p \in \mathcal{C}_1}$ for individual nodes.

That's how I am trying to solve it.

[image: Thats how I am doing it]

Comment: Welcome to math.sx. Please give some more details on your problem. Are you looking for extremal values or why take the derivative and put it zero? Further, your function doesn't make sense $\beta x$ is a vector, while all the other terms are scalars. Is that the source of your problem?

Comment: Thanks Benjamin! Yes I am trying to find extremal values. I have edited my question and have given more detail about specifics of the problem. Hope its understandable now!

Comment: The said problem remains. What type of function are you trying to define? Is it $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$? Then the term $\beta_p x$ doesn’t make sense, because it is vector-valued. Further: I think by derivative you mean gradient. The result should then be a vector, so you should get some sort of vector equation.

Comment: Oh yes! I meant gradient here. So does it make sense then? $\beta_px$ is indeed a vector. The result I am expecting is a vector of same dimensions as v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to put some of your information together, even though your question still does not fully add up.

So let us fix $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, $v\in\mathbb R^n$ and $D\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and define the function
$$ f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R,\ x\mapsto \alpha \|x\|^2+\|Dx\|^2+v^Tx.$$
One can easily calculate (as you correctly did)
$$ \nabla f = 2\alpha x + 2 D^TDx + v. $$
What you are looking for are solutions of the **vector equation**
$$ -v = 2(\alpha I + D^TD )x, $$
where $I$ is the identity matrix. If the matrix $\alpha I + D^TD$ is invertible, you are easily done.

In your question you have another parameter $\beta\in\mathbb R$. However, $x\mapsto \beta x$ is a function $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$, so your function is not well defined. If you instead mean something like $x\mapsto \beta \|x\|$, my answer can easily be adapted to that case.

**Edit to include the above case:**
We want to differentiate a term of the type $\beta\|x\|$. The gradient of $\|x\|$ of course highly depends on the norm you use, I simplify by assuming we are using the Euclidean norm. There, you have the gradient vector
$$ \nabla \|x\| = \frac{x}{\|x\|},$$
so adding $\beta\|x\|$ to the above function definition results in
$$ \nabla(\alpha \|x\|^2+\beta\|x\|+\|Dx\|^2+v^Tx) = 2\alpha x + 2 D^TDx + v + \beta \frac{x}{\|x\|}.$$
Putting this equal to zero and solving this equation is considerably harder than its linear equivalent from above, which is due to the fact that the term $\beta\|x\|$ is a non-linear contribution to the value of your function.

Comment: Hi Benjamin! Thanks once again for your efforts. It is indeed helpful but still I am unable to understand clearly some things.

Comment: (1) Is it necessary to change $\alpha x^2$ to $\alpha\|x\|^2$. (2) The gradient of $v^Tx$ should be $v^T$ not $v$ , Right? (3) Why u have written $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ as my output is x which is still in $\mathbb R^n$. Moreover, I have provided some more details in my question (as I have given my original problem) which might prove helpful for you to answer. Waiting your reply. Thanks

Comment: To (1): What do you mean by $x^2$? I interpreted it as $x^2 = \|x\|^2$ and do not unterstand, what your definition is. You somehow mix up between scalars and vectors a lot. To (2): In my definition $v$ is a column vector, as is the gradient - so $\nabla v^Tx = v$ is correct. To (3): Please add more details in the update. What are the sets $X_1$ and $\mathcal C_1$, what is $\mathcal N_p$ and what is $\gamma_p$?

Comment: Thanks for your point wise answers. It did clarify somethings. For further details you may refer to [link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221663891_D-ADMM_A_Communication-Efficient_Distributed_Algorithm_For_Separable_Optimization) but I guess it's not necessary. Just take all that middle term as $v_p$ which is a vector of same dimensions as output vector $x_p$

Comment: If I mean $x\mapsto \beta \|x\|$, still I get -$\beta-v$ in the end where $\beta$ is a scalar and $v$ is a vector. How to resolve this issue? Thanks once again

Comment: I have added to my answer above. Note, since $\|x\|$ is not linear, this makes the problem way more complicated. Your mistake is to assume $\nabla \|x\| = 1$ (whatever 1  should mean in the vector setting).

Comment: Ok thanks a lot...